# Can't capture queen?

Tags: online-chess

I'm new to chess. Just played a game, my king was on d2, opponents queen was on e1, and my rook was on h1. But the program did not allowed me to capture the enemy queen with my rook, it only allowed to move my king to safety.

Why couldn't I capture the queen with my rook?

Comment: Sounds like you were in double check, but it would be easier to be specific if you posted a full diagram.

Comment: @itub with King on d2 and black Queen on e1, what kind of the double check could it be?? can you imagine any legal move that leads to a double check in that position?

Comment: @lenik: Yes! A pawn promotion on e1. I.e. something like e1Q+ with a black rook on say g2 giving the second check.

Comment: @user1583209 yeah, overlooked that one. thanks!

Comment: If you were in check then you must deal with the check first.

Answer (score 5):

To illustrate what was discussed in the comments above...

If we can exclude computer bugs, or other problems (there were no other pieces on g1, or f1 were there?), the situation you describe is only possible if:

- the last black move was a promotion of a pawn to a queen on e1 (this pawn could have come from e2 or by capture from f2), and...
- a black rook or queen was positioned on h2, g2 or f2

One example of such situation:

```
[FEN "2k5/8/8/8/8/8/3Kp1r1/7R b - - 0 1"]

1... e1=Q+
```

The technical term for this situation is [Double Check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_check) and the only response to a double check is a king move as capturing one piece would still leave your king exposed to a check from the other piece.

For the example above, the only legal moves are 2. Kd3 or Kxe1. If the black queen on e1 was protected by another piece (e.g. by a black bishop from g3), the only legal move for white would be 2. Kd3.